K6 browser how to debug blank page errors?
K6 makes screenshot with blank page when I'm using code from snippet bellow.
I'm supposing that problem is in self signed certificate, but I cannot confirm it.
The question is how to debug it?
My code:
export let options: Options = {
    scenarios: {
        ui: {
            executor: 'shared-iterations',
            options: {
                browser: {
                    type: 'chromium'
                },
            },
        },
    },
    thresholds: {
        checks: ['rate==1.0'],
    },
    insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
};
export default async () => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    try {
        console.log("go to url");
        await page.goto('https://10.99.10.112:8443');
        console.log("screen");
        await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshots/screenshot.png'});
    } finally {
        await page.close();
    }
}

